# React Native - How to use excludedActivityTypes property in ActionSheetIOS options parameter?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to `react native` and i don't have any background in `Objective-C` or `Swift`. The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios#showshareactionsheetwithoptions) does not provide enough content to understand the use of `excludedActivityTypes` property. Documentation says:

> **excludedActivityTypes** (array) - the activities to exclude from the
>   ActionSheet

It takes array but i don't know what to mention in the array and what is the purpose of using this property. Can anyone tell its purpose and how to use it? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's purpose is to remove some options from the list of available actions (like sharing to facebook/twitter or saving to camera roll)

So, in most of the cases you can simply skip it.

```
excludedActivityTypes: [
'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook',
'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter']
```

The list of possible exclusions you can find at Apple's developer documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype

Find more info on this react-native component use here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/153

Comment: Potentially useful: https://snack.expo.dev/@bacon/share:-excluded-activity-types

Comment: how can we exclude our own app from the share sheet?